# Office365 Cert renewal

Tags: exchange, certificate, microsoft-office-365

Do you need to purchase and renew a certificate for a hybrid setup of Exchange and Office365. We have multiple exchange servers setup on site for authentication but none of them have any specific cert installed on IIS that i can see for office365 apart from a third party cert for our *.domainname. Technet does specifiy that you do need a cert to use Office365 in a hybrid setup but I cannot find anything definitively on this. Anyone out there have experience with this setup?

Answer (score 2):

No, Your existing Exchange certificate(s) is used - it's not separate.  That being said that certificate must be from a public CA. If you have internal cert you will need to replace it with a public one. It uses the certificate to validate messages coming from Exchange server.  It uses TLS because it treats these messages as internal which will bypass many of the EOP policies.  It's also used when creating / connecting to migration end point - if the cert is not trusted you would get an error here as well.

When you update your Exchange Certificates - you just re-run the Hybrid wizard to update the Connectors.  You don't have to do anything for the migration endpoints as these are simply checked when accessed.